# Insert XML element without duplicate using python

Tags: python, xml, duplicates

I'm trying to make xml files like this;

```
<root>
<a type="AAA">
    <value1>1</value1>
    <value2>2</value2>
    <value3>3</value3>
</a>
<b type="BBB">
    <value6>6</value6>
    <value7>7</value7>
    <value8>8</value8>
</b>
</root>
```

but when I try to append the xml element, it was like;

```
<root>
<a type="AAA">
    <value1>1</value1>
</a>
<a type="AAA">
    <value2>2</value2>
</a>
<a type="AAA">
    <value3>3</value3>
</a>

<b type="BBB">
    <value6>6</value6>
</b>
<b type="BBB">
    <value7>7</value7>
</b>
<b type="BBB">
    <value8>8</value8>
</b>
</root>
```

here is code. does anybody give some advice how to fix the code to me?

```
xml = Element("root")
for i in list:
    node = Element("a", type=i.type)

    value = Element(i.name)
    value.text = i.value

    node.append(value)
    xml.append(node)
```

thank you so much

Comment: `list` is not iterable. If it's a variable that you set before, please show it in code. (You should also avoid shadowing the built-in variables),  Please make sure you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve, as I still don't know what you are trying to do, let alone where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Do not append within the for loop.
Instead create the node before, append the properties in the loop and append the node to the xml root afterwards.

```
#crete one note before the loop. 
node = Element("a", type=i.type)

for i in list:


    value = Element(i.name)
    value.text = i.value

    node.append(value)

xml.append(node) # append here
```